# how to get the depth value of a ball from a disparity map

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv

Hi I am writing a program which retrieves the z coordinates of a ball from a disparity map. I am using the EmguCv wrapper class. At present I have a lot of elements working although admittedly not perfectly just yet but just need some tweaking. The steps completed so far are as follows:

1. The two cameras operating at the same time with each cameras view displayed in an image box.
2. Camera calibration is carried out with the chessboard squares identified and the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters stored.
3. The images are rectified and undistorted in order to remove as much noise and distortion as possible.
4. I have the ball being identified in each image with the centre of the ball marked and the x and y coordinates retrieved.
5. The disparity map is created and displayed and the reprojectImageTo3D() method implemented to give the x, y and z coordinates of the pixels in the map.

The issue I am having at present is how to isolate the ball in the disparity map in order to get only the x, y and especially z coordinates. I have seen instances where a single object is extracted from a disparity map, e.g. http://disparity.wikidot.com/, under the heading "Adding Color and Motion to Disparity Maps".

Is there a method which could be used in identifying and extracting the ball or is the extraction performed by things such SURF or SIFT processes?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: You might get more answers by asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a lot more details to get a useful answer.

For example, are you looking for a fully automated solution, or is it acceptable to have a human operator provide some input ("hints")? If the latter, the problem becomes a lot easier - a common method is to get mouse input (click) on one or a few pixels in an input image, look up the corresponding depth(s) through the disparity map, then "grow" a fitted sphere from there by adding neighboring pixels - you'll want to start with a lose fit error threshold, and tighten it as the number of added samples increases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally I would like it to become automated in the future but for the moment. At the moment I am working with a live stream. I have the pixel value of the centre of the ball already known in each frame. Would this eliminate the need for a mouse click by using this coordinate? Your second point is exactly what I am looking for. How do I get the corresponding depth of this central pixel? Will the loose fit error threshold obtain this for me?

Comment: In OpenCV? For a (smallish) set of discrete points, use triangulatePoints: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints. For a full disparity map, instead use reprojectImageTo3d: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void reprojectImageTo3D(InputArray disparity, OutputArray _3dImage, InputArray Q, bool handleMissingValues, int ddepth)